# PHP grab images in random order from folder

Tags: php, image

I have a folder containing images and echo them to the page.
This works fine however I want them to randomly change output upon page load.
This is the part that outputs the images:

```
<?php 
$directory = 'somewhere/images/';
$files = getPathsByKind($directory,'svg');
if(!empty($files)) {
    for($i=0; $i < 32; $i++){
        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/'.$files[$i].'">';
    }
}
?>
```

So I thought I'd had to use `rand()` or `array_rand()` but both throw me errors. Which is fine but I have no idea on how to fix them. `rand()` throws me an second parameter error. (`max` and`min` value). Since this is an image there is no second parameter. `array_rand()` won't work because of the loop it isn't an `Array` anymore.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use array_rand() https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_rand.asp

Comment: Create a temporary array with unique indexes, and then finally traverse temp array to output images

Comment: well I'm kind of looking into the possibility to random output the `$i` value

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile. Damn that `shuffle($files)` totally worked. Thanks

Comment: Wordpress? Just curious

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes the `get_bloginfo(template_directory)` kind off gives it away, not?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use `shuffle` function to randomize the array and then output them with your code?

Something like that:

```
<?php 
$directory = 'somewhere/images/';
$files = getPathsByKind($directory,'svg');
if(!empty($files)) {
    shuffle($files);
    for($i=0; $i < 32; $i++){
        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/'.$files[$i].'">';
    }
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Nice answer! I like it.

Answer (score 2):

You question is not clear if you want only 1 image or want all images in a random order.  ( I'm going with all images in a random order );

```
$directory = 'somewhere/images/';
$files = getPathsByKind($directory,'svg');

if(!empty($files)) {

    shuffle($files); //randomly sort array

    for($i=0; $i < 32; $i++){
        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/'.$files[$i].'">';
    }
}
```

You can see an example of shuffle here

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shuffle.asp

PS

> So I thought I'd had to use rand() or array_rand() but both throw me errors. Which is fine but I have no idea on how to fix them

Without seeing what you had I can only guess, my bet would be you tried doing `array_rand()` on something other then `$files` ( possibly inside the loop).

and `rand()` just generates psudorandom number between `$min` and `$max`  so if you did `rand(1,10)` you would expect a number from `1-10`.

Answer (score 1):

Just Use This

```
<?php 
    $directory = 'somewhere/images/';
    $files = getPathsByKind($directory,'svg');
    if(!empty($files)) {
        shuffle($files); //This will sort your array....
        for($i=0; $i < 32; $i++){
            echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/'.$files[$i].'">';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> well I'm kind of looking into the possibility to random output the $i value

You can create an array with number 0->32 and shuffle it, the use foreach to echo the pictures.

Insert this inside your if(!empty()) statement:

```
$arr = range(0,32);
shuffle($arr);

foreach($arr as $i){
    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/'.$files[$i].'">';
}
```